# Wordpress Permalinks 404 Not Found

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, localhost

I have installed the latest WordPress on my EC2 Ubuntu 13.1 server. Once I have changed the permalink to use `/%post-name%/`, I encounter 404 not found for posts. I have followed almost everything here in this article ([Page Not Found - Permalink WordPress — FelfelWorld.com](http://www.felfelworld.com/2013/02/12/page-not-found-permalink-wordpress/)), but still having the issue.

FYI, I remember I did disable the directory listing for my apache server using SELinux (if I remember it correctly)

Comment: can you post your .htaccess, is it like in the blog you postet?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a htaccess issue... try a .htaccess file in the wordpress root with the content (which differs in one line from your posted blog):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

from [Using_Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your webserver has the rewrite module turned on.
eg. If using Wamp and Apache:
Click Wamp tray icon, Apache > Apache Modules > rewrite module (make sure it is selected).

http://www.felfelworld.com/2013/02/12/page-not-found-permalink-wordpress/